# How to create an input stream whose source is the received packet (ByteArrayInputStream and DataInputStream)?

Tags: java, sockets, multicast, datagram

This is a portion of my code (Multicast subscriber to images)

```
public void subscribe() throws IOException {
    byte[] b = new byte[100];
    DatagramPacket datagram = new DatagramPacket(b, b.length, groupAddress, localPort);
    MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(localPort);
    socket.joinGroup(groupAddress);
    socket.send(datagram);

    while(true) {
      socket.receive(datagram); 
      System.err.println("Received " + datagram.getLength() +
        " bytes from " + datagram.getAddress());
      datagram.setLength(b.length); 
      socket.leaveGroup(groupAddress);
      socket.close();
    }
```

Here is the task:

Create an input stream whose source is the received packet (e.g. `ByteArrayInputStream` and `DataInputStream`).

this is publisher:

private void castOneImage(DatagramSocket socket, String imageFn, SocketAddress groupSocketAddress) {

```
    byte[] imageBytes = null;
    try (InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(imageFn);
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Cannot open image file " + imageFn);
        }
        int b;
        while ((b = in.read()) != -1) {
            byteOut.write(b);
        }
        imageBytes = byteOut.toByteArray();

        byteOut.reset();
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.SIZE / 8);
        byteBuffer.putInt(imageBytes.length);
        byteOut.write(byteBuffer.array());
        byteOut.write(imageBytes);
        imageBytes = byteOut.toByteArray();

        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(imageBytes, imageBytes.length, groupSocketAddress);
        socket.send(packet);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // if there is an error for this image, we soldier on hoping other images may be good
        LOGGER.warn("I/O error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ByteArrayInputStream`:

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(datagram.getData(), datagram.getOffset(), datagram.getLength()));
```

And move the `close()` outside the loop. You don't have to leave the group explicitly if you're about to close the socket.

**EDIT** To reconstitute the image data:

```
int length = dis.readInt();
byte[] image = new byte[length];
dis.readFully(image);
```

But of course as datagrams know their own length, you didn't really need to send or receive the `length` word at all.

Comment: how to use this "dis" to retrieve the image sent from it?